# How is the value of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

For a complex number $z$, the infinite sum $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$$ if $|z|<1$. But how can I use $z=-1$ in this formula to claim $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n=\frac{1}{2}?$$

Comment: as it's clear you cannot use that, and also adding infinitely many numbers is not like adding finitely many numbers (that's why you cannot say the sum is zero)

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$ diverges.  So (in the usual meaning) you cannot prove it is $1/2$.  But see "Abel summation" and "Cesàro summation" for other possibilities.

Comment: The summation that you have written (*emphasis on the `summation` that you have written*) does *not* "equal" $\frac{1}{2}$.  The summation as it is written does not converge.  In much the same way, the *summation* $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n$ does not converge and does not "equal" $-\frac{1}{12}$.  There are analytic continuations that take the formulas that work in more restrictive settings (*such as in your case it working only when $|z|$ is strictly less than $1$*) and extend it so that it works in more settings, but that isn't the same thing as the original sum equaling those values.

Comment: As other comments have said, you cannot use the infinite sum identity which you provided by the very condition that $|z|\nless 1$ for $z=-1$. Besides, it's clear that the series does not diverge since it bounces between $1$ and $-1$ based on the parity of $n$.

Comment: @GEdgar I think it does not diverge but oscillates.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 "oscillates" suggests the sum doesn't converge to a fixed value, and is thus divergent by definition.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 the sum clearly diverges, the sequence of partial sums is $1,0,1,0,1,0,...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It said "if $|z|<1,$" and of course if $z=-1$ that is not the case.

According to the most frequently seen "summation method", the expression $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$ means $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N z^n.$ But there are other "summation methods", one of which is "Cesàro summation" (with the "c" pronounced like the "ch" in "potato chip"), in which the sum is taken to be $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac 1 N \sum_{n=1}^N z^n.$ The Cesàro sum of this series is defined when $z=-1$ and is equal to $1/2.$

The function $z\mapsto 1/(1-z)$ has a finite value for $z\in\mathbb C$ except when $z=1.$ It can be expanded in a power series centered anywhere in $\mathbb C$ except at $1.$ For example
$$
\frac 1 {1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-(-2+4i))^n
$$
for appropriate coefficients $c_n$ (which are not hard to calculate). In this example, the series will converge whenever the distance between the center, $-2+4i,$ and $z$ is less than $5.$ That is because $5$ is the distance between the center, $-2+4i,$ and $1,$ which is the one point at which the function does not have a finite value.